# Magento csv import category error

Tags: magento-1.9, category, import

When **import** gives **error** 
**Category** doesn't exist

`_category -> category name`

Error not showing in log file.

Comment: Please share category column.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on below CSV file's screenshot:

[image: CSV should lookalike this]

Answer (score -1):

yes did the same..still the error exist
Category does not exists in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

how can i debug it?

in error log

Warning: Division by zero
template/magentothem/categorytabsliders/categorysale.phtml on line 98
template/magentothem/categorytabsliders/categorysale.phtml on line 238